# Geometry to Instance node is missing in my geometry nodes in Blender 3.1.2

Tags: geometry-nodes

Geometry to Instance node is missing in my geometry nodes. When i open a new file i'm able to see it but can't find with the file i'm working with.Help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the corrupt file? This might help to reproduce your problem.

Comment: hi. I have just uploaded the .blend file. I was following a tutorial and I was tryin to correct the error at the Translate Instance node towards the end of the node.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file with Blender 3.0, where there's no Geometry to Instance nor Merge By Distance.

[image]

You should use 3.1.

[image]